# Phantomjs event handler in c#

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs

I'm using Phantomjs nuget package with Selenium driver to crawl some pages and couldn't find any example, documentation of how to catch phantomjs events in c#

```
var options = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
var _driver = new PhantomJSDriver(options);
_driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
```

I need to check the HTTP status of request(200, 404 etc) using **[onResourceReceived](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-received.html)**. 
Is there any straight forward way to theses events and options available on official website using c#